# How to live angular 4 web app from local to hosting server

Tags: angular, deployment, server, production

I am trying to upload my angular web application to my hosting server.

I've uploaded `dist/` folder files on server to get it run. (But it's only working on root folder)

Let's say my hosting folder name is **`"example.com"`**, so I'll have to upload dist folder files on `example.com/` so this will work fine *(because this is the root path of my domain)*.

But if I will upload dist files into `subfolder example.com/demo/dist files` , this will through an error below

[image]

Please Suggest.

Comment: You need to serve everything in the `dist/` directory, that's the whole point of building it. If you're not using the Angular CLI, then it will depend on the specifics of how your project is set up to build and package the app so nobody can help without more information.

Comment: Why Negative, Was it not sufficient question?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Yes I am using CLI 1.4.5

Comment: Alright, then presumably you've run the build command and uploaded the dist directory to be served per the instructions you've already found. So *what's the problem*? There is nowhere near enough information in this question to tell if you actually have one, let alone what it might be.

Comment: Well, I have uploaded dist folder in this hierarchy `domain.com/angular4/dist/` but when am running it, its coming with error below: 
GET http://www.webtechpie.com/inline.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED
but it's not getting to my folder hierarchy its finding from root

Comment: Please [edit] the question, with more information

Comment: updated kindly check my question again

Comment: Not enough. We've no idea what server software you're running, how it's configured, ...

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: Have you set the appropriate `baseHref` somewhere? It looks like the CLI is assuming the assets will be on the root of the domain, not `/demo`.

Comment: No, how can I set baseHref?

Comment: Given that you're using the CLI, see the options in [the docs](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build).

Comment: I got the solution, changing <base href="/subfolder/"> has fixed that issue